# Custom JSON Serialization Wrapper for Any Object

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I use external application which expects an Object that Serializable from me like his function:

```
externalFunction(Object input);
```

So I should give that function an input that will be correctly serialized into JSON when the method is invoked (not controlled by me).

But I don't know how data is structured since I receive input from another external application dynamically. So case like this:

**1.** Get data from 3rd party

**2.** MyApp should annotate data for Json Serialization

**3.** Send data to 3rd party as input

**4.** Response will be produced as JSON

How can I achieve this? How can I give input to the function that is correctly serialized when the function is invoked?

#### What I tried so far:

So first thing I try is wrap data with some Wrapper like:

```
public class JsonWrapper<T> implements Serializable
{
    public T attributes;

    public JsonWrapper( T attributes )
    {
        this.attributes = attributes;
    }

    @JsonValue
    public T getAttributes( )
    {
        return attributes;
    }
}
```

So I wrap data like ->

```
data = getFromThirdParty();
wrapped = new JsonWrapper<>(data);
externalFunction(wrapped);
```

But it produces a response with "attributes" field which I don't want. Also I tried to use `@JsonUnwrapped public T attributes;` but the result is same.

I don't want this:

```
{
  "attributes": {
      ... some fields/values that I don't know, get from 3rd party
   }
}
```

I want like this:

```
{
  ... some fields/values that I don't know, get from 3rd party
}
```

Comment: I believe the expected output that you have mentioned is not a valid JSON syntax. The inner block must have an identifier key isn't it ?

Comment: My fault, will be updating

Comment: Why do you want to wrap `data` object which you received from `getFromThirdParty()` method. Just pass `data` object.

Comment: Because when I pass data object to the other 3rd party library all attributes are parsed correctly that library has its own, but not mine object. Mine data object is just shown as its toString method instead of proper json.

Answer (score 0):

The [`@JsonUnwrapped`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonUnwrapped.html) annotation doesn't work when `T` is a `Collection` (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13389789/1426227) from the Jackson's creator). But the [`@JsonValue`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonValue.html) annotation actually does the trick:

```java
public class JsonWrapper<T> {

    @JsonValue
    private T value;

    public JsonWrapper(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

If you use [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/), you can have:

```java
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class JsonWrapper<T> {

    @JsonValue
    private T value;
}
```

---

### Example

Consider the following class:

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
}
```

When serializing an `Person` instance, the following result JSON is produced:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonWrapper<?> wrapper = new JsonWrapper<>(new Person("John", "Doe"));
String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(wrapper);
```

```
{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe"}
```

When serializing a list of `Person` instances, the following result JSON is produced:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonWrapper<?> wrapper = new JsonWrapper<>(
        Arrays.asList(
                new Person("John", "Doe"),
                new Person("Jane", "Poe")
        ));
String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(wrapper);
```

```
[{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe"},{"firstName":"Jane","lastName":"Poe"}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can't create Person instance etc. since I don't know which attributes I will receive from the third party. So in my case I will have some Object that I need to wrap it like new JsonWrapper<>(objectReceived). I used @JsonValue as I described but you used it over the field, I think they are same. Also I tried, it again returned with the field "attributes" in my JsonWrapper class.

Comment: @cmlonder `Person` was just an example. It could be anything. The important part is `JsonWrapper<T>` with `@JsonValue`. Which version of Jackson are you using? And, more important, how are you using Jackson here?

Comment: I'm not handling Jackson interactions. Library that I use expects me to return some Serializable objects to them. When I don't add any Jackson annotations, library automatically uses toString method of the Object I put. So for this reason I think that I can somehow make the return value proper json by using JsonValue or similar annotations. When I debug, I see that debug point is triggered when I override toString method and use JsonValue over it or when I use annotation over getAttributes method

Comment: @cmlonder _"Library that I use expects me ..."_ So which library are you using?

Comment: CAS, I didn't want to mention it here since it could get more complicated because either problem occurs because of me while implementing JSON or library itself. I'm examining it too in a separate thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57788482/cas-custom-authentication-handler-principal-json-problem